# Possible causes of java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5

Tags: java, windows

What kind of problem(s) could cause Java's ProcessBuilder.start method to return an IOException with a note saying error=5?

Specifically, we've seen a remote customer system running some Java code along the lines of...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
```

...throw exceptions like this...

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: C:\example\example.exe argument1 argument2 error=5
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at example_code_above
```

We have confirmed that the command noted in the exception, "C:\example\example.exe argument1 argument2" can be run successfully by hand via cmd.exe, so we are confident the command itself is not broken.

Comment: May be error 5 is for "Access Denied". (Not sure)

Comment: i have same issue in android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245238/errorcreateprocess-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Comment: Add after libraries 

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`error=5` means one of:

1) file is not executable
2) file is not accessible

**EDIT**: wont throw exception
<s>3) the command (example.exe) exits with exit code 5</s>

Comment: Thanks - Can you tell me where that information is available for future reference?

Comment: [Windows predefined exit codes](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2347-error-codes-in-windows) and a little bit of experimenting with ProcessBuilder for various cases

Comment: I had this error on Windows 7 too. The reason ? Basically, I have tried to execute a folder rather than an executable :\ Dumb error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245238/errorcreateprocess-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application can you tell about this

Answer (score 9):

Alexandr is correct, it's Windows security that's not allowing that process to run, but that powershell command didn't work for me.  here's what I did:

- Open up Windows explorer, and navigate to example.exe
- Right click on it and choose "Properties"
- Go to the "Security" tab and click the "Edit" button
- Select your username in the top box and in the bottom one give "Full Control" or at least "Read & Execute"
- Click OK to get rid of these boxes

Now your user can execute that program.  Yay!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this happens because the path you put in code is not correct. For windows put `"\\"` as a path separator instead of `"\"` For example change  path to `"C:\\example\\example.exe"`

Comment: The proper escaping is equally important in these posts.  :-)

Comment: I observed this exception in Java, if we use only directory and not the executable or library that starts the process. So check the code if the direct path to the  executable is required.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exception because of Windows UAC.

This can happen even if your account has administrator privileges.

To be able to run such command I had to use powershell to elevate privileges.

```
powershell start-process 'start.bat' -Verb RunAs
```