# Error:CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7-x64, android-studio-2.2

My project was working fine,but now when i try to run my project i am getting following error and not able to run my project,can any one please help me with this?

I am using `Android Studio 2.2` Beta 3, and I have `Windows 7` 64 bit

```
Error:CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: share the code then only we can find

Comment: which code you want me to share?

Comment: The error message is clear enough. The real question is who is calling `CreateProcess`, and what arguments are being passed.

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) might help with troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: If you are not calling `CreateProcess()` from your code, this is a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does CreateProcess give error 193 (%1 is not a valid Win32 app)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637203/why-does-createprocess-give-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-app)

Comment: @RomainFournereau tell me how to solve in android studio

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just marked it as a duplicate. Litteraly the same question already posted AND answered 4 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installation is broken just reinstall Android Studio. In the simplest case just [download the zip file](http://tools.android.com/download/studio) and extract it in your current Android Studio directory.

Just in case start scan your hard drive for errors, maybe you need a replacement.