# Failed to launch SceneBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I downloaded Scene Builder and I was trying to open a .fxml file but there was this error message:

> Failed to launch SceneBuilder. The error message was: Cannot run
>   program "C:\Program Files(x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0":
>   CreateProcess error = 5, Acces is denied

I don't know what this means or how to fix it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Do you tried to start as administrator?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new. How do you start as administrator? Thanks

Comment: Can you actually start SceneBuilder without opening an FXML file? Or can you not start it at all?

Comment: I can use it, but it doesn't work if I open the FXML file with Eclipse.

Comment: From this link `C:\Program Files(x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0`  look for an executable and right-click on it and run as an administrator !

Comment: Yes it worked? Thanks!!

Comment: I recommend you get the latest version of Scenebuilder. http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674431/possible-causes-of-java-io-ioexception-createprocess-error-5), your problem **may** occur when you try to open a file with a no-executable, so you have probably opened your `fxml` file with another type,  for example the program icon.

Comment: I still can't open it from eclipse, but I can open the file from the app. I used this location C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0

Comment: In the context menu do you have the "Open with SceneBuilder" option when you right click on the `FXML` file?

Comment: Yes, there is that option

Comment: Ok, go to **Preferences** then **JavaFX** and verify that you have correctly inserted the location to the **executable** of the SceneBuilder

Comment: I run it as an administrator, but now the error message is "the requested operation requires elevation"

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to stop copy and pasting the path and browse the application manually(scenebuilder).See when you copy the path this is what eclipse run C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder, Yet it is supposed to have C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe try and browse the application path manual not looking for the file location and copy the path

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Reinstall Scene Builder as administrator copying installation path when prompted.

In Eclipse Window > Preferences > JavaFX and click Browse.

Paste Scene Builder Installation path and use tiny arrow top right to view that path.

Scroll until you find SceneBuilder (application - not the icon) and select. Apply and Close.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is Windows permission issue. You can try any of the following:

Try running Eclipse as an Administrator.

[image]

...or give all applications full permission to SceneBuilde.exe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your using a MAC, try this with Java 8. Download scene-builder for Java 8, after set up your run config and download your Javafx libraries to eclipse and computer. Do this and it will create a new controller class for you which you can use as your controller class.

[go to your fxml and do a right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7ua4.png)

Then, set scene builder as your editor [click to see images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxbeo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  This is what worked for me.

In Eclipse **Window > Preferences > JavaFX** I added the complete path including SceneBuilder.exe

C:\Users\ ... AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe

[See: Dialog box mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoWlJ.png)